# Is replacing `this` with a different type allowed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

In the comments and answers to this question:
[Virtual function compiler optimization c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789996/virtual-function-compiler-optimization-c)
it is argued that a virtual function call in a loop cannot be devirtualized, because the virtual function might replace `this` by another object using placement new, e.g.:

```
void A::foo() { // virtual 
   static_assert(sizeof(A) == sizeof(Derived)); 
   new(this) Derived; 
}
```

The example is from a [LLVM blog article about devirtualization](http://blog.llvm.org/2017/03/devirtualization-in-llvm-and-clang.html)

Now my question is: is that allowed by the standard?

I could find this on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) about storage reuse: (emphasis mine)

> A program is not required to call the destructor of an object to end its lifetime if the object is trivially-destructible or if the program does not rely on the side effects of the destructor. However, if a program ends the lifetime of an non-trivial object, it must ensure that **a new object of the same type** is constructed in-place (e.g. via placement new) before the destructor may be called implicitly

If the new object must have the same type, it must have the same virtual functions. So it is not possible to have a different virtual function, and thus, devirtualization is acceptable.

Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Regardless of its legality, I would not worry about perverse code that secretly changes the type of an object at runtime. It was a **big mistake** for the C++ standard to include an example of using placement new to replace an existing object, because it encouraged people to think that doing that actually makes sense.

Comment: seems fine if they are [`covariant`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.virtual#7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you intend to use the new object using handles (pointers, references, or the original variable name) that existed prior to its recreation.  That's allowed only if the instance type is not changed, plus some other conditions excluding `const` objects and sub-objects:

From `[basic.life]`:

> If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or  released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a pointer that pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original object will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object, if:
>
> - the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location which the original object occupied,
>
>   and
> - **the new object is of the same type as the original object** (ignoring the top-level *cv-qualifiers*), and
> - the type of the original object is not const-qualified, and, if a class type, does not contain any non-static data member whose type is const-qualified or a reference type, and
> - the original object was a most derived object of type `T` and the new object is a most derived object of type `T` (that is, they are not base class subobjects).

Your quote from the Standard is merely a consequence of this one.

Your proposed "devirtualization counter-example" does not meet these requirements, therefore all attempts to access the object after it is replaced will cause undefined behavior.

The blog post even pointed this out, in the very next sentence after the example code you looked at.

Comment: Well, should have read further... I stopped at "Is this code even legal? C++ Standard says yes."...

Answer (score 5):

The quote you provided says:

> If a program ends the lifetime of an non-trivial object, it must ensure that a new object of the same type is constructed in-place (e.g. via placement new) before the destructor may be called implicitly

The intent of this statement relates to something a bit different to what you are doing.  The statement is meant to say that when you destroy an object without destroying its name, something still refers to that storage with the original type, o you need to construct a new object there so that when the implicit destruction occurs, there is a valid object to destroy.  This is relevant for example if you have an automatic ("stack") variable, and you call its destructor--you need to construct a new instance there before the destructor is called when the variable goes out of scope.

The statement as a whole, and its "of the same type" clause in particular, has no bearing on the topic you're discussing, which is whether you are allowed to construct a different polymorphic type having the same storage requirements in place of an old one.  I don't know of any reason why you shouldn't be allowed to do that.

Now, that being said, the question you linked to is doing something different: it is calling a function using implicit `this` in a loop, and the question is whether the compiler could assume that the vptr for `this` will not change in that loop.  I believe the compiler could (and `clang -fstrict-vtable-pointers` does) assume this, because `this` is only valid if the type is the same after the placement `new`.

So while the quotes from the standard you have provided are not relevant to this issue, the end result is that it does seem possible for an optimizer to devirtualize function calls made in a loop under the assumption that the type of `*this` (or its vptr) cannot change.  The type of an object stored at an address (and its vptr) can change, but if it does, the old `this` is no longer valid.

Comment: I understand that this paragraph deals with destruction of objects, but it clearly states "the same type". Also later, it reads that pointers/references/etc. are only valid, if (among others) "the new object is of the same type as the original object (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers)". For me this means I can only change CV-qualifiers? But I agree, there is no clear definition of "the same type" here

Comment: Your "the new object is of the same type as the original object" quote describes restrictions on the use of names, pointers, and references to the original storage.  It means `this` cannot be used to refer to the newly constructed object (it has the wrong type), but that does not mean the newly constructed object is not valid.  For example, the original object may have been constructed using placement `new` in an array of `char`, and that array necessarily still exists, so it is legal to `reinterpret_cast` it to the newly constructed type after placement `new` is called.